# Cordova / Phonegap Prevent background music from pausing when using muted inline video

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In my application I am going to show a login-page that features html5 video in the background. The video clip does not contain an audio clip, and the video has the "muted" attribute..

**The code**

```html
 <video webkit-playsinline playsinline autoplay muted="muted" loop poster="resources/video/login_placeholder.png" id="bgvid">
    <source src="resources/video/login_web_noaudio.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**My Question**

When opening this app while playing music in background (e.g. from Apply Music or Spotify), the background music gets ***paused!***

I do not want the background music to get paused. This is terrible for the user experience.

I have tried searching for solutions and plugins, but I have yet to succeed.
Does anybody know how to prevent this media/audio interrupt?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

want to play audio/video simultaneously,

> One alternative solution would be to have the audio inside the video
>   (as the fallback code), then synchronize them using JavaScript.
>   Something like this:

```
<video id="myvideo" controls muted>
    <source src="path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <audio id="myaudio" controls>
        <source src="path/to/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
</video>

<script>
    var myvideo = document.getElementById("myvideo");
    var myaudio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
    myvideo.onplay  = function() { myaudio.play();  }
    myvideo.onpause = function() { myaudio.pause(); }
 </script>
```

just look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ogmjq5m/